Marketing Cloud Cloudpage not appearing in select source in journeybuilder
I create a Cloudpage with Smart capture with "Use in journey builder" enabled and it appears.
I disable and enable "Use in journey builder" and now i cannot find it in the "Define Entry Source".
Multiple Pages with the same issue.
Any suggestion is appreciated.
Clarification and Update:
First of all thank you for your replies.
So basically when you create a new Cloudpage with a smart capture block, you can use it in your journey as the entry.
In order to do that you need to tick "Use in journey builder".
So you save and publish.
If in a later time for some reason you untick the "Use in journey builder" option. The cloud page does not appear as an option in the journey builder, even if you re-enabled it.
In order to reproduce it.

Create Cloud page.
Add smart capture block.
Tick "Use in journey builder" and provide a name.
Save and Publish.
Untick "Use in journey builder".
Save and Publish.
Tick "Use in journey builder" again.
Save and Publish.

This steps will lead to a Cloud page that should be available for selection in the journey builder but it is not.

I had to read this twice, think I get it now; have no solution but please help us understand: The issue is particularly related to this workflow, correct? enable - disable - re-enable
Your problem is: After re-enable it doesnt reappear, but that's what you'd expect?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please share screenshot/more details of the issue or error

After talking with Marketing cloud support they believe that this is some kind of a bug.
The solution they provided is this:
In the CloudPage:
Create a duplicate of the Smart Capture form. This can be done by navigating to the original Smart Capture form and selecting the "Save Block" option located at the bottom of the page.
Next, please choose the "Create New" option. This action will generate a new copy of the Smart Capture form for your use.
We then request that you proceed by replacing the current Smart Form on the CloudPage with the newly created copy.

Navigate to the Content tab.
Carefully click and drag the newly saved content block onto your page.
In the Form Name field, please assign a new name to the form to distinguish it from the original. Please note: It is essential to rename the form to ensure that contacts are correctly injected into the new journey when selected in the entry source.
Once you have completed these steps, click "Done Editing," followed by "Save," and then proceed to "Schedule/Publish" the page

It works.
